# Behaviour of Alpha Dropout in Training and Inference time

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I am in the process of implementing a [self normalizing neural network](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.02515) using the tensorflow. There are currently tensorflow "primitives" in the form of [tf.nn.selu](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/selu) and [tf.contrib.nn.alpha_dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/nn/alpha_dropout) that should make this an easy process. 
My problem is with tf.contrib.nn.alpha_dropout. I was expecting it to have a boolean switch for when you are in training and when you are in inference as does the usual [dropout](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/dropout) function used with other activation functions. 
In the original [implementation](https://github.com/bioinf-jku/SNNs/blob/master/SelfNormalizingNetworks_MLP_MNIST.ipynb) by the authors, we indeed see that they have this boolean switch (training) in the selu dropout function (dropout_selu).

Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

`tf.contrib.nn.alpha_dropout` should be seen as an analogue to `tf.nn.dropout`. [The latter function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dropout) also does *not* have an argument for a training switch. It is not to be confused with `tf.layers.dropout`, which wraps `tf.nn.dropout` and has a `training` argument. As we can see [in the implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.9/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/core.py#L133), the `layers` version returns either the result of `nn.dropout` or the identity depending on the `training` switch. It should be relatively easy to define your own wrapper around `alpha_dropout` in a similar manner.

To avoid any confusion: `layers.dropout` eventually calls the "keras layers" version of dropout which is the implementation linked above.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is all clear now. 
So the solution is to write a wrapper around tf.contrib.nn.alpha_dropout which sets keep_prob to 1 during inference (training == false).